# Correct location of files in android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

ii have a question that i cant seem to find the answer to.
im writing an app in C# using  xamarin on visual studio, and im having some problems with accessing files.

my app read lots of files from the file system, and there are lots of dynamic dll loadings, so i created a batch file that pushes all the files to the android device, to the external storage directory (/storage/emulated/0).
when im running the app through visual studio everything seems to be working fine, but when i try to run the app in release mode or when im trying to run it without the debugger (just clicking the app on my phone) i cant access these files!

it is my understanding that all the application files needs to be put on a special folder for the app, i tried using the Envioremnt.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData and the GetExernalFilesDir function, but when i try to push my files to any of these folders using adb push i get a premission denied error.

so my question is, where should i put my files? they need to be accessable by the app, and the pc (using adb push).

i added premissions to read and write in the manifest.
also rooting the device is out of the question.

any suggestions?
thank,
Meydanb.

Comment: Never assume any paths on the filesystem.  There is no promise of what paths will be on a particular device.  The only safe way is to query for them.  You're also going to have massive permissioning issues.  Each app on the phone is a Unix user account.  So if you just push files, they won't have the right owner and may not be accessible.  Files needed by your app should be part of the apk in assets or downloaded from the internet and stored in your app's storage directory.

Comment: the thing is, im running a webserver on this app, so all of the servers HTML, JS and CSS files should be stored on the device. should i just put all of these files in the assets? we are talking about a couple of hundreds of files...

Comment: Running a webserver on a mobile phone is a pretty bad idea-  its almost impossible to access since it will never have a static IP.  If you're using a webserver to run a local app-  why?  I can't think of a reason to do it, even if your app is an html page there's no reason to run it as a webserver, just view it.  But yes, all your files should be in assets or downloaded.  It is acceptable to move them from assets to the filesystem on first boot (in fact its fairly common).

Comment: this is an app that allready runs on PC and im converting it to Android.
it is just running as a service, and the user should then run chrome to access the site, thats how the system is built, and our client wanted it to run on android...
i know kinda stupid, but thats what needs to be done.
how do i add files as assets? can i add entire folders or do i need to add every file manually?